# Do units get some kind of bonus for being promoted?

Tags: starcraft-2

Units get promoted based on kills -- does this have any effect on their stats or is it just for them to brag about to other units?

Comment: My guess is that this has some use when watching replays, to see how effective units might be...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just for bragging rights. I believe the last rank change is at 20 kills.

Comment: Purely aesthetic in Melee, you can use it in edited maps.

Comment: use it how @tze?

Comment: @Juan if you write a custom map, you can access the variable for how many kills a unit has and process triggers based on it.  How you use it is up the map designer.

Comment: ah, got it, thx