# Does the kill count for a unit affect it in any way?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do units get some kind of bonus for being promoted?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8236/do-units-get-some-kind-of-bonus-for-being-promoted)

In SC2, you can see the kill count for any specific unit. Does this count have any affect on the game? I know there's an achievement for killing 50 with a single unit, but does the kill count actually affect the game in any way? Is there any reason to try to micro units with high kill counts to keep them alive longer (in favor of other units of the same type)?

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of [Do units get some kind of bonus for being promoted?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8236/do-units-get-some-kind-of-bonus-for-being-promoted)

Comment: Oops, I searched before posting, but didn't see that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope! It's completely cosmetic.

I believe it has some built in functionality that can be used in custom games (veterancy) but the number of kills has no effect in either the single player campaign or multiplayer ladder.